# I am site collection admin, but I have no visibility of a group I need to delete

Tags: permissions

As per title, a group has been created, the group owner is me. I am not, however, a member - and due to the way the permission group is configured, only members have visibility of it.

I need to delete this group so I can recreate it with the relevant permissions.

Is there a way to do this through the UI without PowerShell or code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are a site collection administrator, you can do this through the UI. Go to Site Settings and go to People and Groups. Click on your group and then go to Settings, Group Settings. Here you can set the visibility and the owner (I recommend setting it to a group with Full Control, like your  Owners group).

Answer (score 1):

Actually there are pretty straighforward methods to manipulate Site Groups, one way would be directly on the SPSite objects

```
$webURL="http://YouSharePointSite"
$site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($webURL)
$web = $site.OpenWeb()
#list of all groups on site
$groups = $web.sitegroups
```

## or direclty select and delete

```
$groupToDelete = = $web.SiteGroups["YourGroupName"]
$web.SiteGroups.Remove($groupToDelete)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot C Marius, this will be helpful for the future, but I do need a way of doing this without PowerShell.

Comment: ahh, sorry, i've only now see you mentioned "Without". Nagaraju's answers should be fine up to the Point where it should be groupColl.Remove(groupColl.GetById(7));

Comment: I should've explicitly stated through the UI really. I'm guessing it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Sharepoint 2010 client object model,I have not tested below code, but it should work.

```
namespace ClientObjectModel 
{ 
class Program 
{ 
static void Main(string[] args) 
{ 
// Add a new user to a particular group 

string siteURL = "http://serverName:1111/sites/SPSiteDataQuery/"; 
ClientContext context = new ClientContext(siteURL); 
GroupCollection groupColl = context.Web.SiteGroups; 
Group group = groupColl.GetById(7); 
UserCreationInformation userCreationInfo = new UserCreationInformation(); 
userCreationInfo.Email = ""; 
userCreationInfo.LoginName = @"DomainName\UserName"; 
userCreationInfo.Title = "SharePoint Developer"; 
User user = group.Users.Remove(userCreationInfo); 
context.ExecuteQuery(); 
} 
} 
}
```

second option:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/54db21/delete-group-in-sharepoint-2010-programmatically-using-vs-20/